# How can I bind the IQueryable data to the asp gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to bind the IQueryable data to the asp gridview

Here is my code from the controller page. please check it.

```
 public IQueryable<OrdersView> Data()
       {
       NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();
       var a = db.OrdersViews;
       return a;
    }
```

And in the `index.cshtml` page i have used selectMethod to call the method from the controller. I have tried a lot but I can't able to achieve this.

Please note I don't need an `IEnumerable` type but I need just `IQueryable` data to bind for the grid.

Anybody please help me on this query

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make it with `AsQueryable`:

```
var a = db.OrdersViews.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. BTW thers is no use of using .AsQueryable().  I have tried that too. Every time it shows me no record in grid. But the varaible a contains some set of values.

Comment: Can I see your Grid in `index`? Are you using AwesomeMVC?